# How can I use the Lee technical filters with the Seven5 filter holder?

Tags: color-filters

Lee sells a range of 3" / 75mm technical filters. For example, CC40Y (Yellow - Color Compensating Polyester Filter) Manufacturer Code: Y40-P3. These are polyester films for doing color adjustment.

The problem is that the Seven5 75mm filter holder that they sell has slots that are wide and designed for heavy 75mm glass filters.

How do I use the holder with films? Do I just drop the film into the holder loose or is there some way to secure it in the holder with a frame of some kind?

Answer (score 1):

You can purchase a filter holder from Lee.
http://www.leefilters.com/index.php/camera-directory/camera-dir-list/category/mounts-for-polyester-filters
You can make a frame of cardboard to hold the polyester square in your holder. You can just drop in the polyester and let it flop.